# If X or Y condition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I am beginning with rails and I'm trying to create an if condition.

I want to add a S to a word if its length is greater than 1.

```
<% if @user.groups.length == 0 || 1 %>
   <p> débat</p><% else %><p> débats</p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the result : 
undefined local variable or method ` 1' for #<#:0x00007ffbb1c47048>

Comment: @user.groups.lenght > 1 is the answer

Comment: While the logic is indeed a little bit off, there seems to be another issue going on here, because the error is not what I'd expect for that statement... Why is ` 1` being parsed as an identifier, and not a numeric literal?

Comment: @Kick, that would raise a no-method exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%=  "débat".pluralize(@user.groups.length) %>
```

[pluralize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize) Returns the plural form of the word in the string with respect of `count` optional parameter

> ```
>   'débat'.pluralize            # => "débats"
>   'débat'.pluralize(1)         # => "débat"
>   'débat'.pluralize(2)         # => "débats"
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The OR operator needs to be used as below:

```
<% if @user.groups.length == 0 || @user.groups.length == 1 %>
   <p> débat</p><% else %><p> débats</p>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, you can use this way for checking the same condition

```
<% if @user.groups.length < 2 %>
   <p> débat</p><% else %><p> débats</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I fail to see how `> 1` is equal to the originally intended check.

Comment: The equivalent condition is `< 2`, not `> 1` unless you swap the contents

Comment: While this fixes the logic bug, it doesn't explain why an exception was raised. Any idea why ruby was trying to parse ` 1` as a variable/method and not a numeric literal?